# Calculator Random Number Generation on Clicking Operator button

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[Calculator Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rhV.jpg)I am having an issue on calculation in jetpack compose , when i click on number button then it print number, but when i click on any operator it print random numbers.

CalculatorViewModel.kt

```
package hey_viswa.calcmax.viewmodel

import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import hey_viswa.calcmax.action.PerformAction
import hey_viswa.calcmax.action.operation.PerformOperation
import hey_viswa.calcmax.action.state.CalculatorState

class CalculatorViewModel : ViewModel() {


        var state by mutableStateOf(CalculatorState())

        fun userAction(action: PerformAction) {
            when (action) {
                is PerformAction.Number -> enterNumber(action.number)
                is PerformAction.Delete -> delete()
                is PerformAction.Clear -> state = CalculatorState()
                is PerformAction.Operation -> enterOperation(action.operation)
                is PerformAction.Decimal -> enterDecimal()
                is PerformAction.Calculate -> calculate()
            }
        }

        private fun enterOperation(operation: PerformOperation) {
            if (state.firstInput.isNotBlank()) {
                state = state.copy(operation = operation)
            }
        }

        // This function for calculate the input
        private fun calculate() {
            val number1 = state.firstInput.toDoubleOrNull()
            val number2 = state.secondInput.toDoubleOrNull()
            if (number1 != null && number2 != null) {
                val result = when (state.operation) {
                    is PerformOperation.Add -> number1 + number2
                    is PerformOperation.Subtract -> number1 - number2
                    is PerformOperation.Multiply -> number1 * number2
                    is PerformOperation.Divide -> number1 / number2
                    is PerformOperation.Modulus -> number1 % number2
                    null -> return
                }
                state = state.copy(
                    firstInput = result.toString().take(15),
                    secondInput = "",
                    operation = null
                )
            }
        }

        private fun delete() {
            when {
                state.secondInput.isNotBlank() -> state = state.copy(
                    secondInput = state.secondInput.dropLast(1)
                )

                state.operation != null -> state = state.copy(
                    operation = null
                )

                state.firstInput.isNotBlank() -> state = state.copy(
                    firstInput = state.firstInput.dropLast(1)
                )
            }
        }

        private fun enterDecimal() {
            if (state.operation == null && !state.firstInput.contains(".") && state.firstInput.isNotBlank()) {
                state = state.copy(
                    firstInput = state.firstInput + "."
                )
                return
            } else if (!state.secondInput.contains(".") && state.secondInput.isNotBlank()) {
                state = state.copy(
                    secondInput = state.secondInput + "."
                )
            }
        }

        private fun enterNumber(number: Int) {
            if (state.operation == null) {
                if (state.firstInput.length >= MAX_NUM_LENGTH) {
                    return
                }
                state = state.copy(
                    firstInput = state.firstInput + number
                )
                return
            }
            if (state.secondInput.length >= MAX_NUM_LENGTH) {
                return
            }
            state = state.copy(
                secondInput = state.secondInput + number
            )
        }

        companion object {
            private const val MAX_NUM_LENGTH = 8
        }
    }
```

PerformOperation.kt

```
package hey_viswa.calcmax.action.operation

import hey_viswa.calcmax.R

sealed class PerformOperation(val icon: Int) {

    data object Divide : PerformOperation(R.drawable.divide)
    data object Multiply : PerformOperation(R.drawable.mul)
    data object Add : PerformOperation(R.drawable.add)
    data object Subtract : PerformOperation(R.drawable.sub)
    data object Modulus : PerformOperation(R.drawable.percent)

}
```

PerformAction.kt

```
sealed class PerformAction {
    data class Number(val number: Int) : PerformAction()
    data object Clear : PerformAction()
    data object Delete : PerformAction()
    data class Operation(val operation: PerformOperation) : PerformAction()
    data object Calculate : PerformAction()
    data object Decimal : PerformAction()
}
```

CalculatorState.kt

```
data class CalculatorState(
    val firstInput: String = "",
    val secondInput: String = "",
    val operation: PerformOperation? = null
)
```

Component.kt

```
package hey_viswa.calcmax.component

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.shadow
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import hey_viswa.calcmax.R
import hey_viswa.calcmax.action.PerformAction
import hey_viswa.calcmax.action.operation.PerformOperation
import hey_viswa.calcmax.modifiers.bouncingClickable
import hey_viswa.calcmax.ui.theme.errorContainerDark
import hey_viswa.calcmax.viewmodel.CalculatorViewModel

@Composable
fun CalculatorButton(
    icon: Painter,
    iconButtonColors: Color,
    iconColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(shape)
            .background(iconButtonColors)
            .bouncingClickable { onClick() }
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = icon,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = iconColor,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .padding(10.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Calculator() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<CalculatorViewModel>()
    val state = viewModel.state

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
            .padding(15.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            Text(
                text = state.firstInput + (state.operation?.icon
                    ?: "") + state.secondInput,
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 32.dp, horizontal = 15.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                fontSize = 30.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                maxLines = 2,
            )
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.delete),
                    iconButtonColors = errorContainerDark,
                    iconColor = Color.White,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Clear)
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.backspace),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Delete)
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.percent),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Operation(PerformOperation.Modulus))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.divide),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Operation(PerformOperation.Divide))
                    }
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.seven),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(7))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.eight),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(8))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.nine),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(9))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mul),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Operation(PerformOperation.Multiply))
                    }
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.four),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(4))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.five),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(5))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.six),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(6))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sub),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Operation(PerformOperation.Subtract))
                    }
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.one),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(1))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.two),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(2))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.three),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(3))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.add),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Operation(PerformOperation.Add))
                    }
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zero),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Number(0))
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.dot),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Decimal)
                    }
                )
                CalculatorButton(
                    icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.equal),
                    iconButtonColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    iconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(60.dp)
                        .width(140.dp)
                        .shadow(elevation = 5.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.userAction(PerformAction.Calculate)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package hey_viswa.calcmax

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import hey_viswa.calcmax.component.Calculator
import hey_viswa.calcmax.theme.CalculatorTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CalculatorTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Calculator()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    CalculatorTheme {

    }
}
```

I expect to Do calculation , but what's the issue i cant find

Answer (score 0):

###### PerformOperation.kt

```kotlin
sealed class PerformOperation(val icon: Int) {

    val symbolString: String get() {
        return when (this) {
            Add -> "+"
            Divide -> "/"
            Modulus -> "%"
            Multiply -> "*"
            Subtract -> "-"
        }
    }
    ...
```

###### Component.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Calculator() {
....
            Text(
                text = state.firstInput + (
                    state.operation?.symbolString ?: ""
                    ) + state.secondInput,
....
```